# how to put an item in a pagination and show if the item number is greater than 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

On my website, I used pagination for my site. I can not make 6 items per page. For example, if I have 10 items, I have 6 items on the first page and 4 in the other. Also, I can not hide it if there are only 4 items.

I followed the documentation, but something was wrong with my code.

For the hideOnlyOnePage method, I tried hideOnlyOnePage: true;.

Can you help me.

this is my code

```
var lengthOfPage = $('.group').length;
 var defaultOpts = {
            totalPages: 5,
            startPage: 1,
            visiblePages: 2,
            //hideOnlyOnePage: true,
            hideOnlyOnePage: function(){
                if (lengthOfVideosOnPage < 8) {
                   console.log(lengthOfPage);
                    $('#pagin').hide();
                }else{
                    $('#pagin').show();
                }

            },
            onPageClick: function(event, page) {



                $('.page-link').each(function(i, element) {

                    if ($(this).html() == page) {
                        $(this).closest('.page-item').addClass('active');
                    }
                });

            },

        }

        var select = $('#pagin');
        $('#pagin').twbsPagination(defaultOpts);

    }
```

demo https://jsfiddle.net/uLe3bfc5/

Comment: So you have 10 items total and you are wondering why you don't have 6 items on second page?

Comment: here is working fillde https://jsfiddle.net/1t3vo08k/1/ I have moved initialization outside onPageClick function + added bootstrap.css to resources. But I still have no idea what is your problem

Comment: In my website I have 10 divs with class group. I want to show on the first page 4, on the second 4, and on the third 2,  or  on the first page 8 on the secend 2. I have all the content on the same page, and when I click on the pagination, nothing happens.

Comment: Also, I want to learn how to hide (show) dynamic pagination. For example, if I only have 4 divs with a class group that does not display pagination, but if it is higher than four, the content should be displayed on the other side to display pagination. I think that the method of hideOnlyOnePage is used for this purpose. I hope I was not confused and understand. And I'm sorry for my bad English